# Save django request logs in a file

Tags: django, python-2.7, logging

Django shows the requests logs in command line, I want to save that logs in a file. I found a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7045981/1201492) but it saves the logs only that we print manually. Can we save all of the request and response logs in a separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on both linux and windows I hope:

```
python manage.py runserver > logs.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To log the Django request debug events, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435443/544059) about using the [fail-nicely-django](https://github.com/metakermit/fail-nicely-django) config. You will also get 4xx and 5xx request events logged from Django's default loggers.

Note, though, that 2xx requests generally don't get logged by Django, if that's what you are after (only `runserver` shows them in the console). There is a workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942470/544059), but you should generally use your server's access logs for these in production (e.g. *access.log* in nginx/Apache).