# How to configure my Django log to function like the built-in development server log?

Tags: django, django-settings

I am trying to configure my logging configuration in settings.py and there are so many options, I'm having trouble replicating the built-in development server log (that prints to console).

I want my production log to record the same information that would normally be printed to console in the development server log (GET requests, debug info, etc).  I either need to know which settings I need to change below, or the location of the settings for the built-in development server log, so that I can copy that.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
            },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/django/django_log.log',
            'formatter': 'simple'
            },
        },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
            },
        }
    }

if DEBUG:
    # make all loggers use the console.
    for logger in LOGGING['loggers']:
        LOGGING['loggers'][logger]['handlers'] = ['console']
```

I also do not want to have to add any code anywhere else but my settings.py if at all possible.  I don't want to have to go into my views.py and specify what errors to print or log, I never had to do that with the development server, so I'm hoping I can figure this out.

Comment: I am using uWSGI for production, which will redirect all logs (from console) to files. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/

Answer (score 4):

In Django 1.8, the [default logging configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#default-logging-configuration) for a debug environment is:

> When `DEBUG` is `True`:
>
> - The `django` catch-all logger sends all messages at the `WARNING` level or higher to the console. Django doesn’t make any such logging calls at this time (all logging is at the `DEBUG` level or handled by the `django.request` and `django.security` loggers).
> - The `py.warnings` logger, which handles messages from `warnings.warn()`, sends messages to the console.

This logging configuration can be found at [`django.utils.log.DEFAULT_LOGGING`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.5/django/utils/log.py#L23). Note that the catch-all logger actually gets info messages as well, not just warning and above.

When overriding the default logging settings, note that `disable_existing_loggers`, if set to `True`, [will shut up all of Django's default loggers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#configuring-logging).

---

The development server [logs every incoming request directly to stderr](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.5/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L108) like this:

```
[18/Oct/2015 12:08:17] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9946
```

This is specific to the development server and will not be carried over to a production environment, unless you replicate it [with middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942470/880772).